# How can I convert a GDBusInterface into a GDBusProxy?

Tags: c, glib, dbus, gobject, gio

I am trying to write some C that uses the DBus support in GLib's GIO.

I have a `GDBusObjectManager` and I have used `g_signal_connect()` to add a handler to the `interface-added` signal.  The signature of the handler according to the docs is:

```
void
user_function (GDBusObjectManager *manager,
               GDBusObject        *object,
               GDBusInterface     *interface,
               gpointer            user_data)
```

I want to check if the interface that was added matches the interface that I care about (`org.bluez.Adapter1`) and then call some methods from that interface on the object that implements it.  I believe that the first step is to check if the interface name matches.  I believe I could do this by comparing against the return from `const gchar *g_dbus_proxy_get_name(GDBusProxy *proxy);`, but I don't have a `GDBusProxy`, I have a `GDBusInterface`.  So my question is: How can I get a `GDBusProxy` from a `GDBusInterface`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GDBusInterface` is an interface which is implemented by the `GDBusProxy` class, so you already have the `GDBusProxy` — you just need to cast it to the right type, which you can do using `G_DBUS_PROXY (interface)`.

Depending on whether you’re using proxy instances generated by `gdbus-codegen`, you can then either check whether it’s an instance of the proxy for `org.bluez.Adapter1` using a macro from the generated code like `MY_NAMESPACE_IS_ADAPTER1 (interface)`; or you can check the interface name manually using `g_str_equal (g_dbus_proxy_get_interface_name (G_DBUS_PROXY (interface)), "org.bluez.Adapter1")`.

Note that `g_dbus_proxy_get_name()` will return the well-known or unique bus name which the proxy is for, which is not the same as the interface name. A [*well known or unique name*](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#message-bus-names) identifies a peer (typically another process) on the bus. That peer exposes objects at *object paths*, and each object implements one or more *interfaces*.